# How do you import a .accdb file into a python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-import

this is a very basic question, but I am trying to clean up some data for my group, and am trying to just imply import the .accdb file into a data frame format so that I can actually see what I'm dealing with. Can anyone help with this? I also have the series of .txt files that the .accdb file is composed of if that would be easier to import into dataframes individually

Comment: The text files may be easier. Look into using pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pulling MS access tables and putting them in data frames in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790195/pulling-ms-access-tables-and-putting-them-in-data-frames-in-python)

Comment: "[I wouldn't start from there](https://wiki.c2.com/?WouldntStartFromHere)". Do you have any other non-Access data sources you can use instead?

Comment: @Chris I have the .txt files that comprise the .accdb file, and I believe I can just import them into a DF using pandas if I’m not mistaken? Would this be the better route

Comment: Without actually seeing the full dataset it's hard to say what's "better", but text files (assuming they're formatted decently, e.g. as CSV or JSON) are usually nicer to work with than closed binary database formats.

Comment: @Chris it looks like the text files are just a bunch of random text with some numbers interspersed, not in a CSV/JSON format, but none of the code I've tried has come even close to working thus far.

Comment: Then maybe you do need to use the `.accdb` files. Good luck.